# How to formulate this particular learning rate scheduler in PyTorch?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm working with transformer based model, but unable to formulate this learning rate scheduler with PyTorch

```sh
lrate = d_model ^ 0.5 * min( step_num ^ 0.5, step_num * warmup_steps ^ -1.5)
```

Thanks

Comment: fix your image, we dont see anything

Comment: i've removed the image, written it myself. Now have a look